# Application base class from a java bindings library in Xamarin.Android makes Context null, and MvvmCross fail

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a 3rd-party module, which is a Xamarin java bindings library, with some C# classes to make it work in Xamarin.Android. If I create a simple Xamarin.Android project, I can use it perfectly.  But I want to implement it in my big cross-platform Xamarin project, which is using MvvmCross framework.
This 3rd-party module requires to set its own application class to be the base class of the Android application. Normally if you create and application class, you set the Android.App.Application as a base class and decorate it with the ApplicationAttribute.

```
[Application]
public class MyApp: Android.App.Application
{}
```

But if I set the base class to the module's XYZApplication class, which is in java just simply:

```
public class XYZApplication extends Application{}
```

Then the MvvmCross framework fails with this message, when loading the first view:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object  
at Android.App.SyncContext.Post (System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback d, System.Object state) [0x00014] in 
/Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/a1e3982a/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:17 
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidMainThreadDispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction (System.Action action) [0x00025]
```

The line where it fails in `MvxAndroidMainThreadDispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction`:

```
Android.App.Application.SynchronizationContext.Post(ignored => ExceptionMaskedAction(action), null);
```

I checked, the `ExceptionMaskedAction(action)` executes on its own well, so the problem is with the `Android.App.SyncronizationContext`.

What I also found, that after changing the base class `Android.App.Application.Context` becomes null (but strangely the `Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidGlobals>().ApplicationContext` still holds the context correctly). This  might be related to the issue above, something has to be wrong with the `SyncronyzationContext` as well, maybe the Xamarin is not initializing it correctly, or if I change the base class I should do it by hand.

I hope someone has an idea what I am doing wrong, or how I should use a different application base class for Xamarin.Android, to make everything work correctly.

Comment: Can you show more of your stack trace for this exception or is there any more info about what xyz changes? I'm guessing that somehow your custom application is starting the mvx application on an unusual thread somehow - but it's not obvious from the details here - sorry.